# Records missing after insert into table via http request mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, fetch

I am attempting to insert data into a database on aws, a mysql db. I am able to send the data to the endpoint, it shows up for a bit but then dissapears. I am sending it via react. Below is the code I am using:

```
addRecord =() => {
      fetch(`my_ip:4000/data/add?time=${moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:00")}&lat=${this.state.lat}&lon=${this.state.lon}&floor=${this.state.floor}`)
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }
```

API endpoint is in Node below:

```
//add a record 
app.get('/data/add', (req, res) => {
    const { time, lat, lon, floor } = req.query;
    const INSERT_RECORDS = `INSERT INTO table_x(time, lat, lon, floor) VALUES('${time}','${lat}','${lon}',${floor})`;
    connection.query(INSERT_RECORDS, (err, results) => {
        if(err) {
            return res.send(err)
        } else {
            return res.send('successfully added') 
        }
    });
});
```

The records appear in the table for about 5 seconds and then disappear. I believe something is going on with "commiting" in sql but not aware how to fix this.

**Attempt**

I've tried to switch to post as I have seen this in some other posts like:

[Adding data to mysql database with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42423263/adding-data-to-mysql-database-with-node-js)

But still not working. If I use `app.get()` it works but again the data does not persist. it appears in my database for approximately ten seconds, then it simply disappears as if deleted:

```
const SELECT_ALL_PRODUCTS_QUERY = 'SELECT * FROM my_table';
 const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const app = express();

connection.connect(err => {
    if(err) {
        return err;
    } else {
        console.log('success')
    }
});


app.use(cors());

//create api directions
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('go to /products to see products')
}); 

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on port 4000')
});


//call query to select all
app.get('/products', (req, res) => {
    connection.query(SELECT_ALL_PRODUCTS_QUERY, (err, results) => {
        if(err) {
            return res.send(err)
        } else {
            console.log(results)
            return res.json({
                data: results
            })
        }
    })
})




app.post('/add', (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.query);
        var my_data = {
            time: req.query.time,
            lat: req.query.lat,
            lon: req.query.lon,
            floor: req.query.floor
           }
           // now the createStudent is an object you can use in your database insert logic.
           connection.query('INSERT INTO my_table SET ?', my_data, function (err, resp) {
             if (err) throw err;
             // if there are no errors send an OK message.
             res.send('Saved successfully');
           });
    });
```

When I attempt to add a record via:

```
http://my_ip:4000/add?time=2019-10-01%2009:00:00&lat=43.07&lon=-73.08&floor=1
```

I get the error:

CANNOT GET /add

Once again, if I use **`app.get()`** it works but does not persist

When I insert data via the addRecord function I see the following console log on my backend terminal:

```
Server listening on port 4000
success
{ time: '2019-11-24 17:16:00',
  lat: '43',
  lon: '-73.1',
  floor: '0' }
```

So it seems the data is received. But I don't see "saved successfully"

Comment: where exactly are you seeing it show for this brief time? in the aws db? or local DB? (I notice you are using  fetch with `localhost:4000` on the frontend - so i assume you are hitting your backend locally and a local db...so are you looking for the data in the right DB (just worth a double check)  also curious why you are using a GET endpoint to POST data...

Comment: So the API endpoint is in aws. I am not using localhost but hitting the API from react through the aws up on port 4000. Should I be using post vs get for insertion? If so how would I go about altering the code for that?

Comment: typically you would use a POST endpoint and in there (or in a broken out `controller`) call something like `record.save()` (after whatever validation you may want to do -> ALWAYS validate and sanitize everything before you put it in your DB ...ESPECIALLY if it came from user input!!! <--- ), and the corresponding `model` for that class (let's say you have a `records` class) would would be where you define the `.save()` function that inserts into the DB

Comment: to add to the above, you would need for `record` to be a class (you would do that in the model) and instantiate it as `const record = new Record(req.body.recordData)` (or however you pass the data on the body of the post request before you could use `record.save()` on it because `.save()` would be a class function. if you are new and still learning this seems like a lot and don't worry you will get the hang of it, but what you are currently doing is not the way to do it even if it is technically working.... google around a bit on setting up controllers and models, you will get the hang of it!

Comment: circling back to this, data does not just disappear from a DB once it is there without explicitly deleting it .... that would ba a massive failure that DB's rarely have, i have never heard of that...  it's something in your code where you are (next comment...)

Comment: 1) unintentionally deleting it somewhere. (you can confirm it is still there or not by querying the db in the command line or if you have some GUI like positico to see it easier)...  or 2) if your issue is that it disappears from the _UI_ then the issue may be an unintentional re-render where the values are lost on the front-end... not sure where it is disappearing from based on the code i see.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips, I understand needing to secure this properly but for now I am trying to just get this to work so I understand why it doesn't work. I've updated my latest attempt.

Comment: you can't really hit the `/add` route in a browser like you expect because that is a POST route and the browser is making a GET request. Again, DB's don't just _delete_ entries on their _own_... how are you determining that the data is being deleted? are you _looking_ at your DB and seeing it appear and disappear or are you determining this based on seeing it in the front-end for a second then disappearing?

Comment: are you seeing the log: `res.send('Saved successfully');` ?

Comment: No 'saved successfully' but do see console.log(req.query) show up so the function gets there.  Yeah I realized I can't just hit it, but the app.post() seems to sends data to the database. The reason I know it does is because I can see the data on the products/ endpoint from the node script as well as via python where I am hitting the db with a select * from my_table query. After approx 10 secs the data disappears and I am left with 0 records as opposed to the ones that I have inputted from the front end via addRecord(). I've read this could be an issue with rollback. Is that possible?

Comment: well, if it is literally being deleted from the DB after each save then there has to be something wrong with the setup, I have never heard of this happening - i wish i could help but i have to tap out on that one...hopefully someone can jump in! But i would go take a real close look at my backend code and what is happening after each save if there is anything in the code that is not displayed (because i see no reason based on what you showed that would be happening)